# Thread leak detected when using condition variable instead of join() with pthread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, thread-synchronization

I'm new to pthread synchronization, searched "pthread condition variable" in google and grab an example from the pdf: [https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-cv.pdf](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/threads-cv.pdf) .

The example code is as follow, whose purpose is "use condition variable and a variable `done` to implement `pthread_join()`" (as I understand):

```cpp
// https://godbolt.org/z/8rPMq54K8
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

volatile int done  = 0;
pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t c  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
void thr_exit() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    done = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal(&c);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}
void *child(void *arg) {
    printf("child\n");
    thr_exit();
    return NULL;
}
void thr_join() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    while (done == 0)
    {
        pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("parent: begin\n");
    pthread_t p;
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, child, NULL);
    thr_join();
    printf("parent: end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```bash
clang++ main.cpp -fsanitize=thread -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer
```

Running it will see "thread leak" reported:

```
(base) ➜  case12 git:(main) ✗ ./a.out
a.out(71120,0x10433c580) malloc: nano zone abandoned due to inability to preallocate reserved vm space.
parent: begin
child
parent: end
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: thread leak (pid=71120)
  Thread T1 (tid=1365892, finished) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create <null>:74364228 (libclang_rt.tsan_osx_dynamic.dylib:arm64e+0x2bbe8)
    #1 main main_v4.cpp:31 (a.out:arm64+0x100003e38)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: thread leak main_v4.cpp:31 in main
==================
ThreadSanitizer: reported 1 warnings
```

**Is this C++ code really a thread leak, or just a false positive report from tsan?**

Comment: Note that the term is "condition variable" not "condition*al* variable".  And this bears on their semantics, so you should learn and use the right term.  This is in no way pthreads-specific.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you for pointing this out. Now I modified as you suggested.

Comment: You never join with the thread, so the thread data structure still remains. `pthread_join()` or `pthread_detach()` should both fix this. BTW: Use C++ threads!

Comment: Additional note: there is no advantage gained in this program by declaring `done` to be `volatile`.  Volatility is not a means for providing synchronization.  Mutexes *are* a means for providing synchronization, and their proper use for the purpose, as demonstrated in the program, does not in any way rely on the objects protected that way to be declared volatile.

Comment: TLDR: `pthread_join(th,...)` does more than just wait for `th` to terminate. It also cleans stuff up. That's different from how `join()` functions behave in certain other programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this C++ code really a thread leak, or just a false positive report from tsan?

It is really a thread leak, arising from the fact that you cannot implement a substitute for `pthread_join()`.  At least, not in any portable way or based only on the C++ (or C) and pthreads specifications.  The program starts a thread and neither detaches nor joins it before terminating.  That's a thread leak.

The program does successfully and reliably wait to terminate until the child thread provides evidence that it has called `thr_exit()`, but that is not a substitute for joining the child thread.

Comment: Aside from the lack of resource cleanup, there's a second reason why a reliable substitute for `pthread_join()` can't be implemented in user code -- any code the user writes that runs inside the thread has to execute before the thread's entry-function has returned -- but there is additional code that executes (as part of the threading API's thread-shutdown/cleanup routine) *after* the entry-function returns, and without `pthread_join()` being called, that code will still be subject to the race-conditions that `pthread_join()` is designed to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not an answer, just the solution code that I can write, after reading John Bollinger's answer.)

Solution 1:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("parent: begin\n");
    pthread_t p;
    pthread_create(&p, NULL, child, NULL);
    pthread_detach(p);  // !! new added line
    thr_join();
    printf("parent: end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Solution2:

```cpp
void *child(void *arg) {
    pthread_detach(pthread_self()); //!! new added line
    printf("child\n");
    thr_exit();
    return NULL;
}
```